# Hide element and child using CSS (:empty)

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'd like to do the following. This is my element. I'd like

```
<div class="toc uk-panel" style="margin: 0px;"><ol></ol></div>
```

to select this and check, whether it's empty or not. If it is empty, I'd like to hide it.

Using

```
.toc:empty {
     display: none;
}
```

Does not work, because it contains a `ol` element. Is it possible to check, whether the `ol` element is empty and if so, remove both, `ol` and `div`?

Comment: Not possible with css alone, as there is [no parent selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: if you just hide `.toc ol:empty` the parent div should not be visible too (with the code provided)

Comment: There are no parent selectors in CSS, not even in CSS3.

Comment: Hiding the empty `ol` does not hide the parent element. Too bad :-(

Comment: @Tanmay I believe they are adding one to the level 4 selectors spec: https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/

Comment: @Aonghas M: Yes and no. Yes, with `.toc:has(> ol:empty)` (or alternatively `.toc:matches(:empty, :has(> ol:empty))`), no because :has() still hasn't been confirmed to be included in CSS via the live profile.

Comment: @BoltClock thanks for the clarification